# ipset accounting information

Tags: iptables, ipset

I know that iptables keeps accounting information for ip traffic blocked or passed. However, it appears that when using ipsets with iptables, the accounting information is aggregated for the entire set.
Is there any way of finding accounting information for individual entries in an ipset being used by iptables?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [ULOG](http://mohskitchen.wordpress.com/2012/08/27/accounting-with-ulogd-2-and-conntrack-on-a-gbit-nat/) as a target and log the packets by it. Feeding
mySQL/Postgres by ulogd is easy and then you can create such accounting
info as you wish.

Comment: Thanks. I'd turned that up in a google search. Was hoping there was a way to do it which didn't involve anything beyond the kernel and iptables.

Answer (score 0):

I have learned ipset after 6.19 include the accounting information I was looking for, according to http://marc.info/?l=netfilter&m=138289610522990

Comment: Do you have any example how to use it?